# Out of Memory Error in XML Parsing

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I am facing "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: JAVA Heap Space" error while parsing an XML file whose size is more than 350 MB.

PFB the Code Snippet:

```
File file = new File("D:\WS\data.xml");
InputSource source = new InputSource(new FileInputStream(file));
XPathFactory xPathFact = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xPath = xPathFact.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xPath.compile("//person");
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList)expr.evaluate(source, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

I am getting error at the last line where it is trying to evaluate.

Comment: Some XML-Constructs can be very memory-consuming. Can you see anything suspicious in the xml?

Comment: This forum post may be useful https://community.oracle.com/thread/967427?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Did you try to restart everything?

Comment: Are you allocating a specific amount of memory to Java? You could always just add more and see if it will power through.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a less memory consuming approach allowing to treat your target nodes on the fly, indeed instead of having all your nodes in memory which could lead to OOME if they cannot all fit into your heap, it will keep only the current one.

Here is how it can be done with [XMLDog](https://github.com/santhosh-tekuri/jlibs/tree/master/xmldog):

```
XMLDog dog = new XMLDog(null, null, null);
dog.addXPath("//person");
Event event = dog.createEvent();
event.setXMLBuilder(new DOMBuilder());
event.setListener(new InstantEvaluationListener(){
    @Override
    public void onNodeHit(Expression expression, NodeItem nodeItem){
        Node personNode = (Node) nodeItem.xml;
        // Treat your person node here
    }

    @Override
    public void finishedNodeSet(Expression expression){}

    @Override
    public void onResult(Expression expression, Object result){}
});
File file = new File("D:\WS\data.xml");
InputSource source = new InputSource(new FileInputStream(file));
dog.sniff(event, source, false);
```

More details about XMLDog [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jlibs/wikis/XMLDog.wiki).